# Derivative of $|x|$

Tags: derivatives

If $f(x)=|x|$ for $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, what is the derivative of $f(x)$ with respect to $x_i$ if $i\in\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$? I am confused, please show me a hint to get started if you can.

Comment: What do you mean by $|x|$, is it norm $||x||$?

Comment: What's your skill level. Do you know about multivariable calculus, partial derivatives, etc.?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, Anurag A.

Comment: $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume $|x|=\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}$ the euclidian norm. Then

$$\frac{\partial{|x|}}{\partial{x_i}}=\frac{x_i}{|x|}$$

So the total differential is

$$d|x|=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_idx_i}{|x|}$$

Comment: Yes, $|x|$ is treated as the Euclidean norm, like $\|x\|$.